# Invert the 'ed' command for reverting back to previous file version

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ed

I am doing a version control project in Unix using bash script. How can I move from the current version to a previous version without having to build a new file from scratch to the required version. Is there a way to invert the ed scripts to move backwards?

I have a file, and a folder with all the version files (in ed script). The version files containing the ed scripts were created using the command,

```
diff -e $path.$1_dir/.temporaryFile $1 > $path.$1_dir/.v$fileCount
```

`$path` --> variable holding the path, `$fileCount` --> variable holding the version number for the files, `.temporaryFile` --> temp file built to the latest available version.

I am able to build the temporary file from scratch to the latest version using,

```
(cat $path.$1_dir/.v$i) | ed - $path.$1_dir/.temporaryFile
```

`$i` --> iter in a for loop

Comment: Never done this myself, but it seems that if you would use `patch` instead of `ed`, the `-R` should do what you want. Have a look at the *patch* man page.

Comment: Thanks! It was the solution I was looking for. Can you post it as an answer so I can allocate it as the solution that worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `ed` directly, you can use `patch`, which also drives `ed`, and use the -R option to apply the changes in the reverse direction.